# How to filter tabulator on cell element attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, filtering, tabulator

I want to filter my data in tabulator table based on cell style, ex., show all cells with validation failures.

All the examples in the documentation are to filter based on data and the custom functions don't pass cell object to filter on.

Here's example in [codepen](https://codepen.io/manojkakarla/pen/ZEQwrYY?editors=1111)

```js
var columns = [];
$(function () {
  $("#table thead tr th").each(function (i, cell) {
    var name = $(cell).text();
    var field = name.toLowerCase().replace(" ", "_");
    columns.push({
      title: name,
      field: field,
      editor: "input",
      validator: "required"
    });
  });
  var table = new Tabulator("#table", {
    layout: "fitColumns",
    validationMode: "highlight",
    columns: columns
  });
  table.validate();
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 20px;
}
table {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.tabulator-validation-fail {
  background: #f4433624;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.7.2/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.7.2/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Email Address</th>
      <th>Mobile</th>
      <th>City</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Jordan</td>
      <td>Talbot</td>
      <td>Jordan.Talbot@ex.ai</td>
      <td>408 345 3433</td>
      <td>Los Angeles</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Nico</td>
      <td>Rocha</td>
      <td>Nico.Rocha@ex.ai</td>
      <td>408 445 5656</td>
      <td>New York</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cienna</td>
      <td>Bryan</td>
      <td>Cienna.Bryan@ex.ai</td>
      <td>210 454 7799</td>
      <td>Austin</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Vinny</td>
      <td>Hood</td>
      <td>Vinny.Hood@ex.ai</td>
      <td>540 672 2585</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jay</td>
      <td>Lennon</td>
      <td>Jay.Lennon@ex.ai</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Boston</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Helen</td>
      <td>Eaton</td>
      <td>Helen.Eaton@ex.ai</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Chicago</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you want to show only the lines where validation fails?

Comment: @AksJacoves yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get all line objects with the `rowFormatter` object and use the `getElement` method to get the line element `<tr>` along with validate to check whether that line is valid or not, like this:

```js
var columns = [];
$(function () {
  $("#table thead tr th").each(function (i, cell) {
    var name = $(cell).text();
    var field = name.toLowerCase().replace(" ", "_");
    columns.push({
      title: name,
      field: field,
      editor: "input",
      validator: "required"
    });
  });
  var table = new Tabulator("#table", {
    layout: "fitColumns",
    validationMode: "highlight",
    columns: columns,
    rowFormatter: function(row) {
      let valid = row.validate() // if valid, returns true
      if(valid === true) {
        $(row.getElement()).css('display', 'none')
      }
    }
  });
  table.validate();
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 20px;
}
table {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.tabulator-validation-fail {
  background: #f4433624;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.7.2/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.7.2/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Email Address</th>
      <th>Mobile</th>
      <th>City</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Jordan</td>
      <td>Talbot</td>
      <td>Jordan.Talbot@ex.ai</td>
      <td>408 345 3433</td>
      <td>Los Angeles</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Nico</td>
      <td>Rocha</td>
      <td>Nico.Rocha@ex.ai</td>
      <td>408 445 5656</td>
      <td>New York</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cienna</td>
      <td>Bryan</td>
      <td>Cienna.Bryan@ex.ai</td>
      <td>210 454 7799</td>
      <td>Austin</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Vinny</td>
      <td>Hood</td>
      <td>Vinny.Hood@ex.ai</td>
      <td>540 672 2585</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jay</td>
      <td>Lennon</td>
      <td>Jay.Lennon@ex.ai</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Boston</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Helen</td>
      <td>Eaton</td>
      <td>Helen.Eaton@ex.ai</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Chicago</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```